# Ist es korrekt "keywords" in Deutsch zu nutzen?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ist es korrekt, den Begriff *"keyword(s)"* im Deutschen zu benutzen? Oder ist es besser, stattdessen zum Wort *Schlüsselwörter* zu wechseln?

Comment: Ich würde keywords eher vermeiden. Kommt aber auf den Zusammenhang und die Zielgruppe an. Je nach Kontext kann es auch als Stichwort oder Schlagwort übersetzt werden.

Comment: Wie fast immer: Kommt auf den Zusammenhang an. In meinem Berufsumfeld (IT-getrieben mit viel Denglisch) würde ich bei Schlüsselwörter nachfragen was gemeint ist, Unter Keywords kann ich mir etwas vorstellen, würde es aber mit Stichwörter übersetzen.

Comment: *Wenn es ein Schlüsselwort ist, ist es ein Schlüsselwort*. Ohne Kontext kann man schlecht sagen, ob das geht oder nicht, und ich finde die Antworten unten etwas voreilig. Sie könnten u.U. vollkommen falsch sein.

Answer (score 4):

Im Deutschen geht *keyword* nicht, wenn dann *Keyword*, da wir alle Substantive groß schreiben, auch Fremdwörter.

In einem Fachkontext, in dem man das Wort als allgemein gebräuchlich vorraussetzen kann geht es dann schon. Mit Schlüsselwort bist Du aber gut beraten.

Answer (score 4):

The literal translation of the English compound *keyword* would indeed be *Schlüsselwort*, but that’s uncommon and can actually be seen as a mild anglicism and hence poor translation and the actual anglicism *Keyword* might be preferable as an established technical term, e.g. in SEO (search engine optimization) or metadata annotation.

*Schlüsselbegriff*, on the other hand, is idiomatic and so are *Schlagwort* and *Stichwort*. They’re often used in a synonymous fashion, but there are of course fine distinctions in their meaning:

- *Schlüsselbegriff*: The major underlying concept, an identifying phrase, which doesn’t have to actually appear in a text it’s associated with
- *Schlagwort*: A lemma one could look up (*nachschlagen*) in an index, register or glossary, but not necessarily found in a table of contents
- *Stichwort*: The trigger word that activates all kinds of mental associations or actions, e.g. reminding an actor to enter the stage now

In  ontologies, a *Schlagwort* relates more to predefined categories, whereas a *Stichwort* is more like an adhoc tag, but that’s quite open to interpretation.

Related words in special contexts:

- *Fahnenwort*: Used in political linguistics for a motto that unites a party or movement, e.g. *flat tax*
- *Kampfbegriff*: Also used in political linguistics, often a euphemism or seemingly neutral phrase that a certain wing or party has conquered the authority of defining the meaning for, e.g. *axis of evil*
- *Passwort, Kennwort, Losung, Parole*: Passwords of several kinds
- *Schlüssel* (and *Wert*): In key–value pairs

Comment: Bitte schreibe keine englischen Antworten, wenn die Fragestellerin sich extra die Mühe macht, ihre Frage auf Deutsch zu stellen. Möglicherweise möchte sie hier ihre Deutschkenntnisse anwenden. Mit deiner Wahl der falschen Sprache nimmst du ihr aber diese Möglichkeit. - Davon abgesehen: Was lässt dich vermuten, die Fragestellerin würde Englisch besser beherrschen als Deutsch?

Comment: Trotz Hubert Schölnasts (berechtigter) Kritik eine sehr gute Antwort!

Comment: Ergänzungsvorschlag: In Programmiersprachen ist der Begriff *Schlüsselwort* allerdings üblich, siehe [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%BCsselwort_(Programmierung)).